# How to add multiple lists in one list in Xamarin?

Tags: listview, xamarin

I have a list in that different types of data. I took into separate lists. Now i want to push into one list in order. How do achieve it?

```
           For example: list A, (having multiple types of data). i took into 

           B(used data) = A;
           C(unused data) = A;
           D(unwanted data) = A;

           now i want to show data in table view as sorting order E = C+D+B;
```

Comment: it sounds like you are talking about C# Lists, which are not Xamarin specific

Answer (score 1):

```
          List E = new List(); //Create list E

         // Put whatever you want in the E list like below

            E.AddRange(C);
            E.AddRange(D);
            E.AddRange(B);
        Then it will come in rearranged order or sorted order!!
        Hope this will helps you!!
```

Answer (score 1):

What you just asked is a c# query. Xamarin has nothing to do with it. What you can do is, Create a new list, and add into it, all the data from the existing 3 lists that you have in the order which you want. you can also add an entire list in an existing list using the AddRange() method.